# Dynamically creating WorkItems in custom tasks

Tags: jbpm, workitem

I'm doing a PoC to determine if we can use jBPM as an embedded component in our enterprise application.

I'm trying to determine if there is a way for a custom task to not only take in WorkItem objects to the handler, but also to create new WorkItem objects and then pass them on to subsequent custom tasks.  There doesn't see to be the equivalent of WorkItemManager.addNewWorkItem().

What am i missing or am I just approaching this wrong?

Answer (score 0):

WorkItems are internally managed objects, not sure I understand why you would want to pass a work items to the next node.

However, if you are looking at dynamically adding a custom work item to a process instance (note that it would need to be defined as an ad-hoc (sub-)process to be able to do this), you might be looking for this:
https://github.com/droolsjbpm/jbpm/blob/master/jbpm-flow/src/main/java/org/jbpm/workflow/instance/node/DynamicUtils.java#L55